# Why does textContent addition assignment doesn't work with tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation, text-manipulation

I am trying to add some text to an existing element using `textContent`. But when I use `+=`(addition assignment) operator but in the result, already existing tags like `b` has lost its effect. I think I am just adding to it, but it also has effect in the previous content. Can anyone explain why? *I checked the docs but didn't find anything about this.*

HTML:

```html
<div id="divA">Something<b>bold</b></div>
```

JS

```js
const some = document.getElementById("divA");
some.textContent += "Hi"; // This results in : "Something boldHi" without the bolded formatting. 
some.textContent = some.textContent + "Hi"; //This too results in the same!
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `.textContent` value of an element returns just that - the *text content*, which is plain text, not the HTML markup of the contents.

If you do

```
some.textContent += "Hi"
```

The text content of the container will be retrieved, which will not contain any tags - eg

```
<div id="divA">Something<b>bold</b></div>
```

will retrieve:

```
Something bold
```

Concatenating onto that and then assigning the result back to the `.textContent` of the element results in the element's descendants replaced with a *single text node*, where the text node's value is the value assigned.

If you use `.innerHTML +=` instead, the prior HTML markup of the descendants will be preserved - but the descendants will all be re-parsed according to the HTML markup assigned, so event listeners and related things that depend on DOM elements will be lost. A better option is to use `.insertAdjacentHTML`, which does not require re-parsing of the descendants.

An even better option would be to append a node itself instead of trying to write HTML markup (which is potentially unsafe), eg

```
some.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hi'))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are taking the `textContent` then you will get `Somethingbold` which is just plain text wihtout HTML tags

```
console.log(some.textContent); // Somethingbold
```

You are appending the `textContent`, instead you shold use `innerHTML`

```js
const some = document.getElementById("divA");
some.innerHTML += "Hi"; // This results in : "Something boldHi" without the bolded formatting. 
some.innerHTML = some.innerHTML + "Hi"; //This too results in the same!
```

```html
<div id="divA">Something<b>bold</b></div>
```